# clojure get args & exprs of received function

Tags: clojure

My question is: how can I get the args list and expressions of a received function ?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
(defn first-fn [[args exprs]]
  (println "Args:" args)
  (println "Exprs:" exprs))

(first-fn (fn [a b c] (println "something")))
```

So, `first-fn` would print:

```
Args: [a b c]
Exprs: (println "something")
```

My goal is to create a macro that can use the args list of the received function.

Thank you.

---

Edit:

Use case:

I'm using compojure https://github.com/weavejester/compojure
You can define routes like this:

```
(GET "/:id" [id] (body_here id))
```

But I would like to change the syntax to be:

```
(defn handler-fn [id] (body_here id))
...
(GET "/:id" handler-fn)
```

So the handler (body) can be extracted from the routes, and might be reused as well.

I tried to reuse compile-route https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/blob/master/src/compojure/core.clj#L172

```
(defmacro MY_GET [path fn-src]
    (let [fn-fn   (second fn-src)
          arg-vec (nth fn-src 2)
          forms   (drop 3 fn-src)]
      (compojure.core/compile-route :get path arg-vec forms)))
```

But when I call:

```
(MY_GET "/:id" handler-fn)
```

It says: `Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol`

Comment: Can you give an example of the use case for this? It might help to clarify the goal/approach.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with functions, you directly need a macro to do this and even then it is not straight-forward. First, let's explain the difference: macros are basically evaluated at compile-time and the result of this evaluation is then evaluated at run-time. The interesting part is that the evaluation at compile-time gets the literal, unevaluated arguments to the macro as data and not, like normal functions would, the evaluated arguments at run-time. So, your approach cannot work, because at the time `first-fn` receives it's arguments (at run-time), they are already evaluated -- in your example, `first-fn` receives `nil` as arguments. Cf. the [documentation at clojure-doc](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/macros.html) for a much better explanation.

Now, solving your request with a macro requires the macro to parse the arguments (remember: at compile time, code is data) that it receives -- i.e. in your example, it needs to parse the sequence `(fn [a b c] (println "something"))` that builds up the function call you hand over to it. Probably you would want to cover other cases besides the `fn` one (e.g. the # short-hand), that's what it makes the problem not straight-forward in the general case.

This parsing could in the end be handled by a normal function parsing, e.g. a sequence. So, try solving a different puzzle first: build a function `parse-code-sequence` that takes a sequence (that looks like the functions you would hand over) and returns the args and expr -- note the quote (`'`) in front of `fn`.

```
 user> (parse-code-sequence '(fn [a b c] (println "something")))
 {args: [a b c],  expr: (println "something")}
```

Some hints to this: in the example here, which is showing the most used case, the sequence just consists of three elements and you don't need the first one. But the general case is a little bit more complex, cf. the [official documentation on `fn`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/fn).

A final remark: when you implement the macro, you need to think about what it resolves to -- just adding the print-statements is easy, but do you also want to evaluate the arguments normally (so your macro becomes something like a debugging aid) or do you want to do something else?

**Update to reflect your use-case**
Your `MY-GET` macro is not doing what you think it's doing.

1. Take a look at the arguments that the macro gets: why do you think it can magically retrieve the function definition of `handler-fn`, when all that you give as argument to `MY_GET` is the symbol/var `handler-fn`? You would need to retrieve the source, but this usually will not be possible (cf. this SO question on [retrieving the source of a function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782970/how-can-i-display-the-definition-of-a-function-in-clojure-at-the-repl)).
2. You are also missing a backquote before the call to `compile-route`: you want the call to `compile-route` to happen at run-time, not at compile time. Currently, the result of the macro evaluation is the result of the call to `compile-route` (at compile-time). Take a look at `macroexpand` which would show you the result of the macro-expansion. Basically, you want the macro to return the call to `compile-route`.

I don't see any easy way that you could accomplish what you look for. The argument vector of a route definition is defining what needs to be handed over. Even if you extract that to a function definition, compojure still needs to know what to hand over to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you could do.

```
(ns xyz
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)
(spyx *clojure-version*)

(defmacro dissect [ fn-src ]
  (let [fn-fn     (first fn-src)
        arg-vec   (second fn-src)
        forms     (drop 2 fn-src) ]
    (spyx fn-fn)
    (spyx arg-vec)
    (spyx forms)
    ; Here is the return value; ie the transformed code
    `(defn my-fn 
       ~arg-vec
       (apply + ~arg-vec))))

; show the result
(newline)
(println
  (macroexpand-1 
    '(dissect 
      (fn [a b c] 
        (println "the answer is")
        42))))

; call it for real
(newline)
(dissect 
  (fn [a b c] 
    (println "the answer is")
    42))

; use the generated function
(newline)
(spyx (my-fn 1 2 3))
```

with result:

```
*clojure-version* => {:major 1, :minor 8, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}

fn-fn => fn
arg-vec => [a b c]
forms => ((println "the answer is") 42)
(clojure.core/defn tst.clj.core/my-fn [a b c] (clojure.core/apply clojure.core/+ [a b c]))

fn-fn => fn
arg-vec => [a b c]
forms => ((println "the answer is") 42)

(my-fn 1 2 3) => 6
```

Your project.clj needs the following to make `spyx` work:

```
:dependencies [
  [tupelo "0.9.11"]
```

Comment: This seems to work for `fn`
Do you think it would be possible to do the same thing with `defn` ? `(dissec second-fn)` where `second-fn` is declared like this : `(defn second-fn [a b c] (...))`

Comment: Sure, just modify since `(first fn-src)` -> "defn", `(second fn-src)` -> "second-fn",  etc (there is one more token present since there is a function name that `fn` didn't have)

Comment: The problem I get is : `Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol`.
It sounds like I should do something more.